# Empty value yield upon PHP array[key] request

Tags: php, arrays, singleton, void

I have the following code in my KloassiesIcons class:

```
public class KloassiesIcons {

    private static $singleton;
    public static function singleton() {
        if(!(KloassiesIcons::$singleton instanceof KloassiesIcons))
            KloassiesIcons::$singleton = new KloassiesIcons();
        return KloassiesIcons::$singleton;
    }

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function get_icon(string $name = 'thumb') {
        $single = KloassiesIcons::singleton();
        $icon = $single->$icons[$name];

        echo 'iconstring = '.$icon; // this should print "iconstring = what's going on around here?"
                                    // shouldn't it?

        return isset($icon) ? $icon : $single->$icons['post'];
    }

    private $icons = array('thumb' => "what's going on around here?");
}
```

However, when I call upon `KloassiesIcons::get_icon('thumb');` the function yields emptiness **:'-(** 
The `echo 'iconstring = '.$icon;` also only prints "*iconstring =* ", without the value in the array (that should've been stored in `$icon`) combined to it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Should be `$single->icons` - without the second `$`

Comment: I changed the ```echo 'iconstring = '.$icon;``` with

 ```echo 'iconstring = '.$icon;
 print_r($single);
 print_r($single->$icons);
 print_r($single->$icons[$name]);```

which gave the output "*iconstring = KloassiesIcons Object ( [icons:KloassiesIcons:private] Array ( [thumb] => what's going on around here? ) )*" 

After that I put a ```println('bla');``` between all the ```echo```'s and ```print_r```'s which broke the site: WP telling me function ```println``` doesn't exist. I didn't know that - I normally code in Java. Anyways, I won't be able to access the site anymore untill tmw